# How do I use a RichTextEditor (draftail) in wagtail in order to mark different parts of the text with different styles?

Tags: python, django, colors, wagtail, draftjs

**Django Wagtail - Draftail - Multiple color highlighter**

How do I use a RichTextEditor (draftail) in wagtail in order to mark different parts of the text with different styles?

The editor won't display the correct inline styling after saving the document.

There must be something wrong when wagtail reads the style from database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to solve a problem where we wanted to use highlighting feature in a rich text editor in wagtail and I thought i would share my solution since I couldn't find anything solving this problem online.

This solution allows you to highlight different parts of the text with 4 predefined colors.

The main part that solved it for me was

```
tag = f'span{feature_name}'
```

which uniquely could identify the correct spans in the editor.

https://gist.github.com/robodl/48dd4bece30fcaf56c785212931f3bcd

[image: Result when using code with the css]

Hopefully someone will find this useful!